# Menu on-top of a UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiscrollview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I want to create a `UIScrollView` that scroll's only horizontally, with text inside that I'm getting from my server, but I want the text to perform some kind of action when clicked, for example, this is how I want it to look: (separated by "|")

[image: image1]

When you click on ex. `Facebook`, it should perform an action and the `Facebook` should be bold, like a menu. How can I do such a thing? (I'm not looking for code, if someone can provide a clear explanation that will be great!)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Questionable UI decisions aside (how is the user supposed to know these are tappable?) I'd use buttons instead of labels. You can style a button to be borderless and appear as a label would.

Comment: Yes, you are right, it will be easier to add buttons and it's easy to customise them, but this is what the style guide required - what can I do? :( - The user will know that those are clickable because when entering the view, the first default selection will be blue and bolded.

Comment: There is no default selection with a touch screen.

Answer (score 0):

Any UIView (that includes UILabels) can be given a **TapGestureRecognizer**. You just add the gesturerecognizer to the label, and then you can tell it to perform any kind of action you wish.

I would subclass the UILabel class though, to have a object that you can polish and recycle through your project.

Comment: I would avoid both of these choices. UIKit provides `UIButton`, which does exactly what's needed and can be configured in Interface Builder. Gesture recognizers still require the developer to write code, and subclassing is overkill for this use case.